# Flutter firestore have this data or not?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to check if this refer text is available in my firestore data..

```
  void _getRefer() async {
    var result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .where("refercode", isEqualTo: _refer.text)
        .get();
    result.docs.forEach((res) {
      print(res.data()['coins']);
    });
  }
```

if data is not available how can i detect this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

results.size>0 means you have the data stored, otherwise you don't have it

Answer (score 0):

results.size>0 This will help you. If this didn't work then let me know